# My if statement doesn't work with Bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am getting this error:

```
[[: command not found
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IS_PYSTACHE_INSTALLED=$(pip list --format=columns | grep "pystache ")
if [[ ! -z "${IS_PYSTACHE_INSTALLED}" ]]; then
    echo " > Installing pystache"
    pip install pystache
else
    echo " > Pystache is already installed"
fi
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your shell is really Bash? Probably it's something else, for example Dash.

Comment: If you don't have a shebang and you are executing it as a script (such as with `./script` rather than `bash script`), the script is executed with `/bin/sh`, which doesn't support `[[`.

Comment: I do have shebang. I just did not copy the whole code. There was no reason too. The rest works.

Comment: @jnbdz Are you running it with `sh yourfile`?

Comment: I am using this command: . setup.sh

Comment: that command you are using does not execute the script, it sources the script

Comment: I tried it this way: `./setup.sh` I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

if you are unsure of your default shell, go to the terminal and do a `echo $SHELL`, if you see `#/bin/bash` then `chmod` your script and run it like this `./filename.sh` but make sure your hashbang line is `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. If you want to change your default shell to bash use the `chsh` command

Comment: When I `echo $SHELL` I get /bin/bash. Again most of the script executes ok. It just that part that throws an error.